# Marionette / Backbone routing and controllers with require.js

Tags: backbone.js, routes, requirejs, marionette

Could someone please explain/provide an example how to get this routing thingy to work in Marionette.

I would like to get console.log("stuff") after navigating to /#test.
This is what I have so far and it does absolutely nothing (no errors though...):

main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: '/',
  paths: {
    'text': '../vendor/javascripts/requirejs-text/text',
    'backbone': '../vendor/javascripts/backbone/backbone',
    'backbone.wreqr': '../vendor/javascripts/backbone.wreqr/backbone.wreqr',
    'backbone.babysitter': '../vendor/javascripts/backbone.babysitter/backbone.babysitter',
    'jquery': '../vendor/javascripts/jquery/jquery',
    'jquery-ui': '../vendor/javascripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui',
    'json2': '../vendor/javascripts/json2/json2',
    'marionette': '../vendor/javascripts/marionette/backbone.marionette',
    'underscore': '../vendor/javascripts/underscore/underscore',
    'handlebars': '../vendor/javascripts/handlebars/handlebars'
  },
  shim: {
    'underscore': {
      exports: '_'
    },
    'backbone': {
      deps: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'json2'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'marionette': {
      deps: ['backbone'],
      exports: 'Marionette'
    },
    'jquery-ui': {
      deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'handlebars': {
      exports: 'Handlebars'
    }
  }
});

define(["app"], function(App) {
  return App.start();
});
```

app.js:

```
define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'backbone', 'marionette', 'view', 'router'], function(_, $, Backbone, Marionette, View, Router) {
  var App;
  App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
  App.on("initialize:after", function() {
    var router, view;
    view = new View();
    return router = new Router();
  });
  return App;
});
```

router.js:

```
define(["marionette", "controller"], function(Marionette, Controller) {
  var AppRouter;
  AppRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    controller: Controller,
    appRoutes: {
      'test': 'testStuff'
    },
    initialize: function() {
      return console.log('router init');
    }
  });
  return AppRouter;
});
```

controller.js:

```
define ["marionette"], (Marionette) ->

    Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend
        initialize: ->
            console.log 'controller initialized'

        testStuff: ->
            alert 'stuff'


    # create an instance
    Controller = new Controller()
```

Comment: can you try with no route, just put "" : "testStuff"  in your appRoutes, or leave the route as is and make sure your route in the browser looks like this http://yoururl.html#test

Comment: or it may be that you didnt added the app  file path in yout require configuration, so It should be at the same level of your main require file, is it?

Comment: I've tried to put "":"testStuff" instead of the route and I've also checked the file paths.. Nothing. Everything works as expected, all the files are there and loaded ok, but still the route doesn't work. If I change the name "testStuff" in my controller it complains that "testStuff" was not found on the controller, as expected. So it is looking for a right method in the right place, but still it doesn't seem to work... :/

Comment: So I got as far as to add "if (Backbone.history) {
  Backbone.history.start();}" and got it sort of working. Well, it still doesn't alert "stuff" when I go to the given url, but by going to some other url and then hitting back the route seems to fire... strange. Now I would need to figure how to get it work when entering the url directly. Any advises on where to put that history part? Now I've got in in my app.js, on initialize:after

Comment: if you have just one router, I think after you initialize your router you can start the history

Comment: Yes! AFTER I initialize the router, not before. That's it, now it's working! Thank you

Comment: glad I was able to help you find the answer, post the answer and accept it so others can find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this thing got solved:

Needed to add

```
if (Backbone.history) { 
  Backbone.history.start();
}
```

after initializing the router